# How to implement Google Earth style zoom in/out and pan animation in ArcGIS Engine applications?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine, google-earth, animation

I am developing an application using ArcGIS Engine 10 and the C# language.

I wish to add some more animation capabilities into my application.

In other words, I want to add animation to zoom in, zoom out and pan like the animation in Google Earth's pan and zoom in/out.

I use OpenStreetMap (OSM) maps for the base map and also have other local layers in my application.

Is there any way to use animations like Google Earth animation for zoom in/out and pan to act with my map ?